# Есть текстовый файл, добавляя в него имена пользователей мне надо чтобы они формировались в столбик

Tags: python

```
filename = 'programming.txt'
counter = 0
with open(filename, 'a') as file_object:
    while counter != 5:
        user_name = input('Enter your name please ')
        file_object.write(user_name)
        counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

добавь в свой код "\n". Вот так:

file_object.write(user_name+"\n")

И все должно работать.